# Regex match word and surrounding text with braces

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a code like this:

```
111
{
    text
    text
    text
}
222
{
    text
    target_word
    text
    text
    can be any number of lines 
}
333
{
    text
    text
    text
}
```

And I'm trying to match everything up and down from target word, including both braces and "222" in this case, so it would match this:

```
222
{
    text
    target_word
    text
    text
}
```

What would regex expression be for that? Preferably working in Notepad++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
\d+\r?\n\{[^\{]*?yourword[^\{]*?\r?\n\}
```